# UITable view scrolled up by half of UISectionHeader

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem that My UITableView is always scrolled up by maybe the half of Section Header. 
I have a custom Section Header which is 44 pixel height.

[image]

After a scrolling down and release the focus the table view gets to his good position. The bug happes only after init.

[image]

here is my `viewDidLoad` code :

```
    [self.tableView removeUsslessSeparators];
    [self.tableView setEstimatedRowHeight:50];
    [self.tableView setEstimatedSectionHeaderHeight:0];
    [self.tableView setSectionIndexColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#000000"]];
    [self.tableView setSectionIndexBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.tableView setRowHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];
    [self.tableView setSectionHeaderHeight:UITableViewAutomaticDimension];

    [self.tableView registerNib:[VOIOrbitContactsListSectionHeader nibRepresentation] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:[VOIOrbitContactsListSectionHeader preferredIdentifier]];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[VOIOrbitContactCell nibRepresentation] forCellReuseIdentifier:[VOIOrbitContactCell preferredIdentifier]];

    self.searchBarController = [VOISearchBarController searchViewControllerWithDelegate:self];
    [self containerAddChildViewController:self.searchBarController toContainerView:self.searchControllerContainer useAutolayout:YES];


    [self.searchControllerContainerTopOffsetConstraint setConstant:75];
    [self.tableViewTopOffsetConstraint setConstant:self.searchControllerContainerTopOffsetConstraint.constant + 4] ;
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake( self.searchControllerContainerHeightConstraint.constant , 0, 50, 0)];

//    CGPoint offset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
//    self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;

 //   [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];

    [self checkIfPlusButtonNeedsToBeHidden];
    [NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName:VOCChangeNotificationNameForEntity([VOCOrbit class]) usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
```

I was trying to use different solutions to scroll down a bit the table view programatically. but none of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.searchControllerContainerTopOffsetConstraint setConstant:75];
[self.tableViewTopOffsetConstraint setConstant:self.searchControllerContainerTopOffsetConstraint.constant + 4] ;
```

Dont use the content offsets rather give the position of the table directly to:

```
[self.table setframe:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
```

Then, Pass your header frame as Header Of Table

```
table.tableHeaderView = yourHeaderView;
```

Hope, this will work for you.